# std::function bound to member function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

The following code doesn't compile in VS2012

```
class Zot
{
public:
    int A() { return 123; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::function<int (Zot*)> fn = &Zot::A;
    return 0;
}
```

However, changing the assignment to

```
    std::function<int (Zot*)> fn = std::bind(&Zot::A, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Does work.

There are a lot of online examples that show the original syntax.  Did something change in the C++11 spec to disallow this syntax?

Is there a valid shorter form for the assignment?

**Edit**: the compiler error (slightly edited for reabability) is:

```
1>vc\include\functional(515): error C2664: 'std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Set' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Rx,_V0_t> *'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Rx=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *
1>          ]
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>          vc\include\functional(515) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__thiscall Zot::* const &)(void),_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *,
1>              _Fret=int,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,Zot *>>,
1>              _Fty=int (__thiscall Zot::* const &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          vc\include\functional(515) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__thiscall Zot::* const &)(void),_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *,
1>              _Fret=int,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,Zot *>>,
1>              _Fty=int (__thiscall Zot::* const &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          vc\include\functional(515) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,Zot,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_Fret (__thiscall Zot::* const )(void),_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *,
1>              _Fret=int,
1>              _Ty=std::_Func_class<int,Zot *>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,Zot *>>
1>          ]
1>          vc\include\functional(515) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,Zot,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_Fret (__thiscall Zot::* const )(void),_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *,
1>              _Fret=int,
1>              _Ty=std::_Func_class<int,Zot *>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,Zot *>>
1>          ]
1>          vc\include\functional(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Reset<int,Zot>(_Fret (__thiscall Zot::* const )(void))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *,
1>              _Fret=int
1>          ]
1>          vc\include\functional(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,_V0_t>::_Reset<int,Zot>(_Fret (__thiscall Zot::* const )(void))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int,
1>              _V0_t=Zot *,
1>              _Fret=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\..\cxx11.cpp(17) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty>::function<int(__thiscall Zot::* )(void)>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=int (Zot *),
1>              _Fx=int (__thiscall Zot::* )(void)
1>          ]
1>          c:\...\cxx11.cpp(17) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty>::function<int(__thiscall Zot::* )(void)>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=int (Zot *),
1>              _Fx=int (__thiscall Zot::* )(void)
1>          ]
```

Comment: Compiles and runs as expected on VS2010 and [GCC 4.7.1](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a6cbf79a13b0ac7f92b454b82b259482)

Comment: Luc Danton's analysis sounds reasonable to me: this looks like it may be a bug and at a minimum warrants further investigation.  If you would, please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and post a link here so others can find it.  In the meantime, I'd recommend using `std::mem_fn` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks -- I've filed the bug report as: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759806/cant-assign-std-function-with-member-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work. One of the requirements on the functor argument for any of the appropriate constructor (e.g. `template<class F> function(F f);`) of `std::function<R(ArgsTypes...)>` is:

> f shall be *Callable* (20.8.11.2) for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R`.

(20.8.11.2.1 functionconstruct/copy/destroy [func.wrap.func.con])

In turn, "*Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R`" is a Standard quasi-concept (for lack of concepts) defined in terms of the pseudo-expression `INVOKE(f, declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`. This pseudo-expression unifies regular functors, which are invoked with the usual call syntax (e.g. `f(a, b, c)`), with pointers to members which have their own quirks (e.g. `p->*a` or `(r.*a)(b, c)`). *INVOKE* is defined in 20.8.2 Requirements [func.require].

Furthermore, the effects of using the call operator of `std::function` include `INVOKE(f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)` (20.8.11.2.4 function invocation [func.wrap.func.inv]), meaning that the 'right' thing is done for pointers to members.

There are in fact a lot of other things that are also defined in terms of *Callable*/*INVOKE* in the Standard, like `std::bind`, `std::thread`, `std::reference_wrapper` and `std::result_of`*.

*: in particular this means that something like

```
template<typename Functor>
typename std::result_of<Functor()>::type apply(Functor functor)
{ return std::forward<Functor>(functor)(); }
```

is problematic at least for that reason.

Answer (score 5):

The following syntax works and is shorter at least:

```
std::function<int (Zot*)> fn = std::mem_fn(&Zot::A);
```

Comment: why `std::mem_fn(&Zot::A)` works but `&Zot::A` does not. Please explain.