# std::vector that holds class methods

Tags: c++, vector, enums, std, std-function

I have done this to enumerate my class members

```
enum MemberType {A, B, C, D};

class Hello
{
public:
    std::vector<std::function<void(Hello*, void)>>     m_members;

    void func()
    {
    };

    Hello()
    {
        m_members[A] = func();
    }
};
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you had an extra `void`:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(Hello*)>>     m_members;
```

Then, you need to assign something more like this:

```
m_members[A] = &Hello::func;
```

Or you can store bound functions, in which case `std::function<void()>` and `std::bind(&Hello::func, this)`.

Comment: I have a problem with this code and I guess the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145035/stdfunction-bound-to-member-function I should add there `std::mem_fn`, but I don't know what is it, and why your code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

1) Before calling `m_members[A] = ...` you need to reserve space in `vector` :) Anyway, here's how you can make things work:

```
class Hello
{
public:
    std::vector<void(Hello::*)()> m_members;

    void func()
    {
        cout << "func" << endl;
    };

    Hello()
    {
        m_members.push_back(&Hello::func);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Hello obj;
    (obj.*obj.m_members[A])();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```